# Breaking a while loop in a called Function

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

On clicking the start button the function RunB() executes the while loop . I need to break the while loop execution midway using the Stop Button .

```
switch (msg)
{

case WM_CREATE:
    CreateWindow(TEXT("button"), TEXT("Browser"),
        WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,
        30, 100, 80, 25,
        hwnd, (HMENU)1, NULL, NULL);
    CreateWindow(TEXT("button"), TEXT("Stop"),
        WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,
        30, 200, 80, 25,
        hwnd, (HMENU)2, NULL, NULL);
    break;

case WM_COMMAND:
    if (LOWORD(wParam) == 1) {
        Obj.RunB();
    }
    break;
    if (LOWORD(wParam) == 2) {
        //Code to break the while loop

    }
    break;
```

Code for the Called Function RunB:

```
void RunB(){
    while(n<15){
    //Some statements here:
    }
```

How do I break the while loop using the Stop Button ?

Comment: Not going to happen, until you wrap your head around the event-based model of Windows applications. Get yourself a copy of Petzold's [Programming Windows®](https://www.amazon.com/dp/157231995X).

Comment: To do so, you must run your while loop in a separate thread.

Comment: To be fair, it is possible without threads, by calling `PeekMessage` in the while loop. But no ideal.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: Multithreading is the last option I would suggest. You could also decompose the `while`-loop into `WM_TIMER`-callbacks. Either way, though, you first need to understand, how Windows applications work. Point in case: Message handlers run to completion before another message can be handled (approximately correct).

Answer (score 1):

The event driven action (i.e. pressing a button), shouldn't engage a looping or business logic.... Otherwise the whole windows will be halt until it gets the synchronous response.

Comment: Yes , that is right but how do I ensure that the window gets continuous synchronous response when the loop runs because this halt also does not allow me to click any other button until the loop finishes itself .

Answer (score 1):

If you find you have some modal action that is going to take a long time to complete and you absolutely can't break it up, then you need to periodically process messages from within your modal action.

For example:

```
while(n<15){
  DoAPieceOfWork(n);
  FlushPendingMessages();
}
```

And FlushPendingMessages would be implemented something like:

```
void FlushPendingMessages(){
  MSG msg;
  while(PeekMessage(&msg,0,0,0,PM_REMOVE)){
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
  }
}
```

This will keep your application mostly responsive. Normaly you would also display a modeless dialog at the same time, so that people know your application is busy and cannot be interacted with.

To be more correct, before calling TranslateMessage/DispatchMessage you must also check for WM_QUIT and repost it to terminate your app, and you can also explicitly check for WM_APP+x messages- using code something like this:

```
#define WM_APP_QUITLOOP  (WM_APP+1)

// use this from anywhere to tell your processing loop to quit
PostMessage(NULL,WM_APP_QUITLOOP,0,0L);

BOOL FlushPendingMessages(){
  MSG msg;
  while(PeekMessage(&msg,0,0,0,PM_REMOVE)){
    switch(msg.message){
    case WM_APP_QUITLOOP:
      return FALSE;
    case WM_QUIT:
      PostQuitMessage(msg.wParam);
      return FALSE;
    default:
      TranslateMessage(&msg);
      DispatchMessage(&msg);   
    }
  }
  return TRUE;
}
```

Your processing loop would need to check the return value from `FlushPendingMessages` and abort if its FALSE of course.

---

Edit: as per @IInspectable's comment.

Comment: Your `PostQuitMessage`-call should really forward the exit code, i.e. `PostQuitMessage(msg.wParam);`.

Comment: Oh great, now instead of recommending the innocuous looking `DoEvents` function in the [.net] tags, we're recommending implementing our own version in the [winapi] tag. I mean, yes, this will work, and sometimes it makes sense, but the advice needs to come with an unmistakable caveat. The people who ask this type of question are the least likely to be able to use this to good end.

Comment: @ChrisBecke Now on clicking the Start button the program works but i can't click the Stop Button . The application does not respond to any action/click .